# pass ffmpeg options through mlt xml

Tags: ffmpeg, mlt

I'm looking at an MLT XML file that I created with `kdenlive` and would like to tweak the command line options passed to `ffmpeg`.

If I understand correclty, this is the part that I need to edit:

```
 <consumer f="mp4" g="15" channels="2" crf="15" progressive="1" target="thetargetfile.mp3" threads="0" real_time="-3" format_options="-stillimage" mlt_service="avformat" vcodec="libx264" ab="256k" movflags="+faststart" bf="2" preset="faster" acodec="aac" in="0" out="18263"/>
```

Now, I would like to pass an additional flag to `ffmpeg`, in my case `-stillimage` for still image optimization of the output (my file is a recorded slideshow presentation, so there's really no excuse for it being hundreds of MB large).

Is there an option in that allows to just pass arbitrary flags to `ffmpeg`, or how else would I go about performing such an optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

The proximate issue is, how to pass on stillimage.
The underlying issue is, how to reduce file size of a slideshow.

For `stillimage`, it is a type of tuning of the encoder, so the format would be `tune="stillimage"`. See https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/ConsumerAvformat/#tune-3

However, that tuning will produce a modest benefit, or possibly no benefit at all.

The two key parameters creating a larger file are

```
g="15" ... crf="15"
```

Such a low CRF value is wasteful unless the resolution is fairly low (< 360p). Keep it at around 23.
With such a low `g` value, a lot of keyframes are generated which will bloat file size. For a slideshow, a default of 250 is usually fine.